# Angular 9 + Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular

I've transferred my app to my other laptop and getting this error in the console. Any idea why this is happening?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at
>   Object.../../node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/core.js
>   (vendor.js:133069) at webpack_require (runtime.js:85) at
>   Object.../../node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/index.js
>   (vendor.js:135192) at webpack_require (runtime.js:85) at
>   Object.../../node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js
>   (vendor.js:130507) at webpack_require (runtime.js:85) at
>   Object.../../node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js
>   (vendor.js:130871) at webpack_require (runtime.js:85) at
>   Object.../../node_modules/@babel/types/lib/utils/react/cleanJSXElementLiteralChild.js
>   (vendor.js:137453) at webpack_require (runtime.js:85)

Comment: This error is not enough to understand problem. Please share your package.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this into index.html header and try

```
<script>
    //var global = global || window;//open this if you take global error
    //var Buffer = Buffer || [];//open this if you take buffer error
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: Yes, that got rid of the error, but getting another error: core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quiz'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quiz'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4396)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4360)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)

Comment: Did you try to upgrade version ?  and when you transform to new pc are angular cli versions are same with past one  ?

Comment: I upgraded to latest version but then downgraded back to 9.0.4.

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028782/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment for your error ?

Comment: I was trying to use path alias in tsconfig, maybe that's why.

Comment: When you directly try to open page from url , Is it working ?

Comment: tried loading http://localhost:4200/quiz/intro but doesn't load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215439/discussion-between-integral100x-and-pc-coder).