# unable to route component over current component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

I am new to angular and working with routing and got stucked in a situation where I am calling *question.component* from *body.component* and want to replace it with *question.component* but getting error. Following is my code

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HeaderComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: BodyComponent, outlet:'secondary'},
      { path: 'ask', component: QuestionComponent, outlet:'secondary'}
    ]
  },
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**header.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-toolbars">
  <span>Header</span>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!isLoggedIn">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Login<mat-icon>login</mat-icon></button>
  </ng-template>
     <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" >
        <span (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
        </span>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
<div id="contentwrapper">
   <div class="main_content">
     <router-outlet name="secondary"></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```

**body.component.html**

whenever i click on ask button its not routing the *question.component* over body.component

```
<mat-card class="card-container">
<button mat-raised-button color="success" [routerLink]="['ask']" skipLocationChange> <mat-icon>speaker_notes</mat-icon> Ask Question</button>
</mat-card>
```

**Error**

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/ask'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/ask'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:3387)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:3351)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028782/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment/52028799

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the outlet for `ask` path to secondary outlet so may be you have not added the secondary outlet

```
 <router-outlet name="secondary"></router-outlet>
```

and using that link like this

```
<mat-card class="card-container">
<button mat-raised-button color="success" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { secondary: ['ask'] } }]" skipLocationChange> <mat-icon>speaker_notes</mat-icon> Ask Question</button>
</mat-card>
```

Check this POST

[Child Routes Angular](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets)

[angular-router-series-secondary-outlets](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-router-series-secondary-outlets-primer-139206595e2)