# How do i declare good routes in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Im using angular and wanted to try lazy loading with multiples modules,  and i getting this error **Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/users/profile'**

So well i been like a few long hours trying to solve this problem but i foundno answer

APP MODULE

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./components/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./components/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home',
  },
```

HOME ROUTING MODULE

```
 {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../users/users.module').then((m) => m.UsersModule),
  },
```

USERS ROUTING MODULE

```
 {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'child',
    component: UsersComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    outlet: 'child',
    component: UserComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    outlet: 'child',
    component: ProfileComponent,
  },
```

Here is the repo if you need to see something else **https://github.com/ginebras/user-system**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise), Cannot match any routes. URL Segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028782/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need for using named outlets, you are complicating things for yourself. Let's keep it simple, So I removed 'child' from your `<router-outlet>` as well as removed `outlet: child` from your routes.

I updated your User's Routing in `user-routing.module`, It should look like this:

```js
  RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
      {
        path: 'user-detail/:id',
        component: UserComponent,
      },
    ]),
  ],
```

I also changed the `user:/id` path to `user-detail:id` for readability. You can change it back or you change from where you are opening `user:/id` to `user-detail:id`.

I update the stackblitz too, have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmxi8g?

Comment: Thank u very much ill try that as soon as i can, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you very much, as soon as i remove the outlets from the routes it worked out, thanks!

Comment: @AlejøFrancø, welcome. If the answer helps, you can mark it as selected to help the other people viewing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Alejø.

Most likely you need to remove this line

```js
component: HomeComponent,
```

You need to use `component` or `loadChildren` but not both. You can put the `HomeComponent` as an empty path in the home routing module. Don't forget `pathMatch: 'full'` on ***all*** your empty paths.

Comment: Thank u very much i thought i could use it, because in the course video the instructor did that so i thought i could, thank u very much for the help.